# Why does System.Guid not implement System.IConvertible?

Tags: c#, clr, guid

I recently tried to return an object of type [Guid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx) from a method accepting `<T>`, however the compiler gave me the following error:

> The type **'System.Guid'** cannot be used as type parameter **'T'** in the
>   generic type or method 'MyGenericMethod'. There is no boxing
>   conversion from **'System.Guid'** to **'System.IConvertible'**.

After investigation I realised that the compiler message was caused due to the Guid type not implementing the System.IConvertible interface.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.aspx) states the following:

> This interface provides methods to convert the value of an instance of
>   an implementing type to a common language runtime type that has an
>   equivalent value.

The provided list of types does not include Guid; Can anyone explain/provide a use case as to why this is the case?

Comment: What would a Guid mean in terms of any other type but a string?

Comment: @leppie, quite a bit as a byte[] for storage as an Oracle Raw for example.

Comment: @JustinHarvey Nope, the SO editor took <T> and though it was some sort of tag.

Comment: It might indeed mean a lot as a byte[], but IConvertable only converts to the basic types, and that doesn't include byte[].

Comment: @Jamie Keeling, can you also say what constraints you had on the generic, as you must have had some to genrate that error?

Comment: @MatthewWatson: It does, via [`ToType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.totype.aspx).

Comment: @JustinHarvey *where T : struct, IConvertible* .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[IConvertible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.aspx) requires the type be able to convert it's data to most of the primitives. How would you represent a Guid as a float for example?

Because Guid cannot implement most of the interface methods it's expected to not declare itself otherwise.

Now on the real question: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: `DateTime` is an example of `IConvertible` almost all methods of which throw `InvalidCastException`. `DBNull` is even worse.

Answer (score 1):

Using System.Guid as type parameters for generic methods is not a problem as the following code shows. Can you please post the implementation of the MyGenericMethod method and also the code calling that method?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new GenericTest();
        test.MyGenericMethod(Guid.NewGuid());
    }
}

class GenericTest
{
    public void MyGenericMethod<T>(T t)
    {
    }
}
```

I am guessing that the method implementation has a type constraint requiring the type parameter to be of IConvertible and therefore looks something like the following.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new GenericTest();
        test.MyGenericMethod(Guid.NewGuid());
    }
}

class GenericTest
{
    public void MyGenericMethod<T>(T t)
        where T : IConvertible
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: *I am guessing that the method implementation has a type constraint requiring the type parameter to be of IConvertible.* Spot on! I had a look at the source (its an internal method) and noticed it required IConvertible, hence my compiler error.